# "None" returned during scraping

Tags: python

My code currently creates the following output during scraping: https://pastebin.com/pUcCdbMn.

I want to get the text in `listing-title`, i.e

```
<h2 class="listing-title"><a class="listing-fpa-link" href="...">Vauxhall Astra 1.6i 16V Design 5dr Hatchback</a></h2>
```

return **Vauxhall Astra 1.6i 16V Design 5dr Hatchback**

`listing-key-specs`, i.e.

```
<ul class="listing-key-specs">
<li>2015
(65 reg)</li>
<li>Hatchback</li>
<li>14,304 miles</li>
<li>Manual</li>
<li>1.6L</li>
<li>Petrol</li>
</ul>
```

return **2015 (65 reg), Hatchback, "14,304 miles", Manual, 1.6L, Petrol** all as seperate variables.

How can I accomplish this? My code currently returns `None` when I try to extract the listing title:

```
for page in range(1, 3):
    page_count = str(page)
    if page is 1:
        url = "http://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=sponsored&radius=1500&postcode=se218qe&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New"
    else:
        url = "http://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=sponsored&radius=1500&postcode=se218qe&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&page=" + page_count
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    cars = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'search-page__result'})
    cars_count = len(cars)
    print 'Processing ' + str(cars_count) + ' cars found on page ' + page_count

    # Loop through cars on page
    for car in cars:
        car_name = car.find('h2 ', {'class': 'listing-title'})
        print car_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this extra space after a tag name:

```
car_name = car.find('h2 ', {'class': 'listing-title'})
                 # HERE^
```

Remove it and it should start working as is.

Note that, to get the text of the title, use `get_text()` method:

```
print(car_name.get_text(strip=True))
```

You can also replace the `.find()` with `.select_one()`:

```
car_name = car.find('h2.listing-title')
```

---

I would also make the script more reliable and [explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the search results to appear before reading the page source and passing it for further parsing:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# ...
browser.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-page__result .listing-title")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
```