# Extracting li element and assigning it to variable with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Given the following element

```
<ul class="listing-key-specs ">

        <li>2004 (54 reg)</li>

        <li>Hatchback</li>

        <li>90,274 miles</li>

        <li>Manual</li>

        <li>1.2L</li>

        <li>60 bhp</li>

        <li>Petrol</li>

    </ul>
```

How do I extract each li element and assign it to a variable with beautiful soup?

Currently, my code looks like this:

`detail = car.find('ul', {'class': 'listing-key-specs'}).get_text(strip=True)`

and it produces the following output:

```
2005 (05 reg)Saloon66,038 milesManual1.8L118 bhpPetrol
```

Please refer to the following question for more context: ["None" returned during scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460522/none-returned-during-scraping).

Comment: what output you need

Comment: I need to extract the text in each li element in the ul class listing-key-specs and assign it to a variable.

Comment: The entirety of my code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460522/none-returned-during-scraping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check online DEMO](https://repl.it/HSYK/1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc="""
<ul class="listing-key-specs ">

        <li>2004 (54 reg)</li>

        <li>Hatchback</li>

        <li>90,274 miles</li>

        <li>Manual</li>

        <li>1.2L</li>

        <li>60 bhp</li>

        <li>Petrol</li>

    </ul>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
lst = [_.get_text(strip=True) for _ in soup.find('ul', {'class': 'listing-key-specs'}).find_all('li')]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are calling `get_text()` on the ul tag, which simply returns all its contents as one string. So
`<div>
    <p>Hello </p>
    <p>World </p>
</div>`
would become `Hello World`.

To extract each matching sub tag and store them as seperate elements, use `car.find_all()`, like this.

```
tag_list = car.find_all('li', class_='listing-key-specs')
my_list = [i.get_text() for i in tag_list]
```

This will give you a list of all `li` tags inside the class 'listing-key-specs'. Now you're free to assign variables, eg. `carType = my_list[1]`